# Is there a way to name and refer to a assumption in Isabelle apply-scripts?

Tags: isabelle

*Is there any way in Isabelle (2021) to refer to assumptions in the old apply style proofs?*

In particular, I am interested in using the assumptions as facts in the `OF` operator so that I can do (hypothetically):

```
apply(rule R[OF assm1  assm4])
```

, where `assm1` and `assm4` should refer to the 1st and 4th assumptions in the current proof state.

Often times, I can arrange assumptions of the current sugboal so that `R[OF assm1  assm4]` is the same as the subgoal. But then, I can't finish the proof because I don't know how to refer to `assm1 assm4` etc. It seems that only global theorem names are allowed with `OF`.

I even tried to use the `subgoal_tac` method on the assumptions, but it does not seem to have an option of giving names to the fact.

In the end, I have to use an automatic script such as `simp`, which is somewhat opaque for something so obvious. By the way, this is for learning purposes. I tried setting up `simp_trace`, but still couldn't replicate the effect without using `simp`.

Moreover,

*If there is no way to refer to assumptions, is this a limitation of the tactics or a fundamental limitation of natural deduction?* (i.e. Is the rewriting style of `R[OF assm1  assm4]` not compatible with natural deduction?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point is Isar is that you can name assumptions...

The first low-level solution is to use `drule` (or `frule` to keep the assumptions).

Here is an example:

```
lemma
  assumes ‹⋀x y. P x ⟹ Q y ⟹ R z› ‹P x› ‹Q y›
  shows ‹R z›
  using assms(2-) apply -
  apply (drule assms(1))
  apply assumption
  apply assumption
  done
```

Look at [Chapter 5](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021/doc/tutorial.pdf) for details on the destruction/elimination/intro rules.

The second solution is `subgoal`:

```
lemma
  assumes ‹⋀x y. P x ⟹ Q y ⟹ R z› ‹P x› ‹Q y›
  shows ‹R z›
  using assms(2-) apply -
  subgoal premises p
    by (rule assms(1)[OF p])
  done
```

but this creates hard-to-read proofs if you have very deep nesting.

The third and best solution is to use Isar proofs…

Here is a version that completely avoids using names:

```
lemma
  assumes ‹⋀x y. P x ⟹ Q y ⟹ R z› ‹P x› ‹Q y›
  shows ‹R z›
  using assms apply -
  apply (elim meta_allE[of _ x])
  apply (elim meta_allE[of _ y])
  apply (drule cut_rl)
   apply assumption  
  apply (drule cut_rl)
   apply assumption  
  apply assumption
  done
```

You can see how ugly this is and why you should avoid that.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand you correctly, this requires stating the lemma using `fix ... assumes ... shows`. Otherwise, low-level statements of the statements with only \<And> and ==> etc. do do not have a way of supplying names. Is it correct?

Comment: I have added the example where you avoid naming the assumptions. It is a very ugly because you cannot name facts (except by using `subgoal`).